# The main components of container look broken while visiting other sub-project pages in Micro-frontend

Tags: reactjs

We are using Micro-frontend architecture for our project with Reactjs. The app consists of container sub-project which includes the main components and page structure that all other sub-projects should also have (like header, footer, some widgets, sidebar...)
The issue is that I noticed that some components of the container sub-project looked destroyed and very ugly in production when I navigated to the pages of other sub-project. What is causing such an issue? We are using React with Material UI.

Comment: The reason maybe that the styling is not getting loaded or getting overwritten for your sub components. Can you inspect the style changes when they are opened with Container and without container? This might point you as to if it is overwritten or it is not loaded.

Comment: If you do not give us any code, or how you call your styles files into your project or anything we won't be able to help you even if we want. If you have the repo and  it's public share it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because of CSS collision. If you are using Material UI and take the benefits of it's CSS in JS implementation in all sub-projects then it's better to generate unique CSS class prefixes for each sub-project for not facing such an issue because some CSS in JS libraries will not really generate random prefixes. Here is what you can do in App.js files of each sub-project:

```
import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: 'ad',
});

...

 <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
   <div>
      ...
   </div>
 </StylesProvider>
```

For example for above sub-projects CSS classes will be generated with `ad` prefix. Make sure to do the same for all sub-projects but use different prefixes that is close to that project for example above one is for admin, used `ad` . In this way you will overcome CSS collision since every sub-project will have it's own class prefix generated.

Comment: It looked like that was really CSS collision and your answer solved the problem. I was trying to solve it about 2 weeks. Thank you!